# Flex: Cancel HTTPService.send()?

Tags: apache-flex, httpservice

OK I have an `HTTPService` that executes the `dataLoaded(e:ResultEvent):void` function whenever it gets a result from a send() call.

OK so If I call `HTTPService.send()` and then call `HTTPService.send()` again before the previous one receives a result, I end up repeatedly running `dataLoaded()` which is undesirable

What I want is if `HTTPService.send()` gets called before a previous call to it returns a result. I want to cancel the first call, and only process the result from the last call to `HTTPService.send()`

I hope this makes sense.

How can I do that??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually HTTPService can manage this for you. It has a *concurrency* property, which you should probably set to "last".

More info here: [HTTPService#concurrency](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#concurrency)

Comment: Hi All,

How stop the execution of HTTP Service when when it is in the middle?.

My Scenario;
I make a Search Service that is search patient from DB from a front end Text Input.

If user change the text that he/she enter before i send the service call again but i want result on base of last entered text, the first one call that i send() i want to destroy or stop it.

How i achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#cancel()

Answer (score 6):

HTTPService has a cancel method. If you call it without its parameter, it should cancel the last invocation of the service. Give that a try and see if you're still getting undesired ResultEvents.

Use the existence of the ASyncToken to determine whether cancellation is appropriate.

```
private var _serviceCall:ASyncToken;

function callMyService(stuff:Object):void {
    if (_serviceCall !== null) {
        myService.cancel();
        _serviceCall = null;
    }
    _serviceCall = myService.send(stuff)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Robert's answer: [Flex: Cancel HTTPService.send()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156420/flex-cancel-httpservice-send/2156992#2156992)

HTTPService#concurrency seems to be introduced until Flex 4, I don't find this in Flex 3.*. In Flex 3.*, you have to cancel the previous call manually in contrast to concurrency="last" in Flex 4.

Note that this won't interrupt server process that previous call invokes, it means server may still come out a response however flex abandon that already.

Comment: My mistake, I found this property in latest Flex 3.6, seems my 3.x doc is pretty old.